# Suppose $V=\Bbb R_2[x]$ and $W=\{p(x) \in V: p(1)=0\}$. Define a subspace $U=\{T:V \to V : W \subseteq \operatorname{Ker} T\}$, find $\dim U$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $V=\Bbb R_2[x]$ (all polynomials of degree $2$ or less), and $W=\{p(x) \in V: p(1)=0\}$. Define a subspace $U=\{T:V \to V : W \subseteq \operatorname{ker} T\}$. Find $\dim U$.

I know $W$ is all polynomials of the form $a+bx+cx^2$ that satisfy $a+b+c=0$, so the dimension of $W$ is $2$.

I tried finding a basis for the homomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$, whose dimension is $9$. Four elements from its basis are $T(a+bx+cx^2)=a$ , $T(a+bx+cx^2)=bx$ , $T(a+bx+cx^2)=cx^2$, $T(a+bx+cx^2)=bx^2$ and so on.
However, I can't seem to find a way to force the condition of $W$ on the elements of the basis of the homomorphism, so I can't find the dimension of $U$.

Comment: My bad @AnneBauval It seems $6$ as $T$ maps two dimensional space into $3$ dimensional one.

Comment: If you want a matrix version of @AnneBauval 's answer: using the usual basis $1,x,x^2$ of $V$ we have that $W$ consists of all matrices with $0$ entries in the first column. That leaves six free choices, so dimension $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U\cong Hom(V/W,V)$ hence $\dim(U)=(3-2)3=3.$

Comment: What does the symbol $≅$ mean?

Comment: Is isomorphic to